# Changing the color of lines in a group

Tags: vba, visio

I'd like to change the proprieties of the lines in my schematics.
The code works, except if lines are in a group.

```
Dim shp As Visio.Shape
For Each shp In Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection
    '// Add cell and formula/results here:
    shp.Cells("linecolor") = 0
Next shp

Set shp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you make your "bonus question" a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

For each shape you need to check the number of shapes within the group, viz.

shp.shapes.count > 0

then iterate over those shapes setting your line color there as well.

For each shp2 in shp.shapes

Of course, each of these shapes may also be a group, so a recursive routine is called for here.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to work properly, indeed, if there are subgroups it's not working so I'll try to find how to set up a recursive routine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final code, in case someone else will be looking for the same problem:

```
For Each shp In Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection
shapeCount = shp.Shapes.Count

If shapeCount > 0 Then

For Each shp2 In shp.Shapes

 '// Add cell and formula/results here:
 shp2.Cells("linecolor") = 0

 Next shp2
 End If

 Next shp
```

Comment: Also look at [layers](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-layers-to-set-properties-for-multiple-shapes-e61f432b-998c-461a-b99c-c6fbcc5c62e5) in Visio. They are give you a way of changing the color without touching every shape. You can use the [layer.CellsC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.layer.cellsc) property to change the color of the layer in VBA.